# Changing objects value

Tags: java, list, object

I am troubled by the way you can change fields in objects without actually using the operations on them.

for example say I have the following class:

```
public class MultisetPair {
    private Object element ;
    private int cardinality ;
    public MultisetPair(Object element) {
        this.element = element ;
        cardinality = 1 ;
    }
    public Object getElement() {
        return element ;
    }
    public int getCardinality() {
        return cardinality ;
    }
    public void setCardinality(int cardinality) {
        if(cardinality < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.cardinality = cardinality ;
    }
}
```

and I have a list of MultisetPair objects like so:

```
LinkedList<MultisetPair> multilist = new LinkedList<>();
```

and I do something like:

```
MultisetPair pair = multiset.get(3);
pair.setCardinality(pair.getCardinality()+1);
```

this doesn't just change the cardinality of the pair I just created , it will also make the cardinality of the pair at multisetpair(3) greater by one.

why is that? shouldn't it change just the pair I created and not the actual one?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the Javadoc of List's `get()` method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)):

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

As per the docs, it **returns** element present at specified location and doesn't create a **new** instance. What you get is a reference of the element present at position 3. So, when you make a change, it gets applied to the existing element as we haven't created any **new** element anywhere in this code (there is no constructor invocation in the code).

Answer (score 1):

```
MultisetPair pair = multiset.get(3);
pair.setCardinality(pair.getCardinality()+1);
```

> this doesn't just change the cardinality of the pair I just created it will also make the cardinality of the pair at multisetpair(3) greater by one.

Because these two objects ... are the **same** object. There are't **two** objects above. You have a local variable `pair` that references the content of your list at position 3. That is all there is to this.

When you put an egg into a box, and you leave the box open, and you then select the third egg in that box, and colour it ... then that third egg in that box gets colored.

In other words: you can have multiple *references* that point to the *very same* underlying object. And it doesn't matter which reference you use to access that object, as soon as you change the state of that object, that one object gets updated.